# Pass functions to stencil component

Tags: html, function, web-component, stencils

Is it possible to pass a function to a `stencilJs` component?

Something like:

```
@Prop() okFunc: () => void;
```

I have a modal and want to dynamically call a passed function on the `Ok` button clicked in the modal footer, like an `onClick` on a normal HTML button.

Comment: just found out, that one can do somthing like this: `@Prop() okFunc: string;` then in the footer of the Component `<my-button onClick={() => this.okClicked()} text="Ok"></my-button>` and `okClicked = () => {
        eval(this.okFunc);
    }`

Comment: `okClicked = () => {
        var  func = ( new Function( 'return ' + this.okFunc ) )();
        func();
    }` is better than `eval(this.okFunc);`

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can. It is just a normal `@Prop()` declaration and plays very nicely in TSX. However...

As noted in another answer and comments, if you are consuming a Stencil component in plain ol' HTML, you will not be able to use Stencil's attribute-prop binding to pass a function (or any non-scalar value) to a prop via an HTML attribute.

### Use the DOM API

This means that *you have to interact with the DOM* if you want to attach events or pass function props to Stencil components. Once your component makes it into the DOM, there is really nothing special about it compared to any other Custom Element.

Without JSX or another template DSL (e.g. Angular), you will need to attach events and set your function- or object-reference props with the JavaScript DOM API:

```
const componentInstance = document.querySelector('my-stencil-component')

// This works and will trigger a rerender (as expected for a prop change)
componentInstance.someFunc = (...) => { ... }

// This works for any event, including custom events fired from Stencil's EventEmitter
componentInstance.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', (event: MyCustomEvent) => { ... })
```

If you absolutely **must** do this in your HTML document for some reason:

```
<my-stencil-component ... >...</my-stencil-component>
<script>
  var componentInstance = document.currentScript.previousElementSibling
  componentInstance.someFunc = function(...) { ... }
</script>
```

---

#### Why do I have to do this?

It's important to realize that `Properties ≠ Attributes`. Props are [JavaScript Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/property/JavaScript), in this case, properties of the DOM object representing an element. [Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Attribute) are XML attributes, although HTML attributes have some unique characteristics and behave slightly differently than typical XML.

Stencil will automatically "bind" HTML attributes to properties for you where possible - in particular, for scalar values (`boolean`, `number`, `string`). Object references, and therefore functions, cannot be used as the value of an attribute. Technically, only `string`s can be attribute values, but Stencil is smart enough to convert `string` to other another scalar type (`boolean` or `number`) when you specify the type of your `@Prop()`.

---

### Other Solutions

I developed a solution for my team to bind attributes containing JSON to Stencil properties using a `MutationObserver`. It basically watches for a special attribute `bind-json`, then maps attributes starting with `json-` onto the corresponding camelCase DOM properties. Usage looks like this:

```
<my-stencil-component
  bind-json
  json-prop-name='{ "key": "value" }'>
</my-stencil-component>
```

With the `MutationObserver` in place, this is identical to:

```
const componentInstance = document.querySelector('my-stencil-component')
componentInstance.propName = JSON.parse(componentInstance.getAttribute('json-prop-name'))
```

However, there really is not a satisfying solution for binding *functions* in plain HTML. It really just can't be done without some sort of ugly hack like `eval` described in another comment. Not only does that pollute your component's API, it's problematic for [all kinds of other reasons I won't get into here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) and its use will automatically fail your app in practically any modern security check.

In our Storybook stories we bind callback function definitions to the `window`, and use `<script>` tags and `document.currentScript` or `querySelector` to pass the function props and event bindings to the component instance:

```
const MyStory = ({ ... }) => {
  window.myStoryFunc = () => { ... }
  window.myStoryClickHandler = () => { ... }
  return `
    <my-stencil-component ... >...</my-stencil-component>
    <script>
      const componentInstance = document.currentScript.previousElementSibling
      componentInstance.someFunc = window.myStoryFunc
      componentInstance.addEventListener('click', window.myStoryClickHandler)
    </script>
  `
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a `@Prop() someFunc: Function` to any component and pass it from the outside like 
    `<any-component someFunc={() => console.log('coming from the outside')} />`

Within anyComponent just check `if (this.someFunc) { this.someFunc() }`

Comment: I can't pass a function from vue into a stencil component. I means can't assign function into <any-component someFunc={myVueFunction()} />?What to do on this situation!? it takes myVueFunction as string.

Comment: Is there any solution for my situation!?

Comment: @SuriyaKumar If you use `<any-component someFunc={myVueFunction()} />` you'll get the return value of `myVueFunction` instead of the actual function. To pass the function remove the `()` - so you don't call the function at the time you want to pass it. Correct solution: `<any-component someFunc={myVueFunction} />`

Comment: above solution works only in JSX (React) . As Stencil is universal web component this is not the correct solution.