# How to prevent onClick on disabled button in StencilJs

Tags: javascript, stenciljs, stencil-component

I have created my own custom button as below

```
@Component({
    tag: "idv-button",
    styleUrl: "idv-button.scss",
    shadow: true,
})
export class IdvButton {
    @Prop({ reflect: true }) text: string;
    @Prop({ reflect: true }) disabled: boolean = false;

    render(): any {
        return (
            <button disabled={this.disabled} onClick={this.onClick}>
                <span class="btn-text">{this.text}</span>
            </button>
        );
    }

    private onClick(event: Event): void {
        if (this.disabled) {
            console.log("prevent default", event); // it doesn't come here at all
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

}
```

and used it like this in another component in stenciljs

```html
                        <idv-button
                            text="my button"
                            disabled={true}
                            onClick={this.startClick.bind(this)}>
                        </idv-button>
```

the problem is although the button is `disabled` and even I tried to prevent default, onClick still happening and `this.startClick` is called

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How about adding `pointer-events: none` to the button?

Comment: @terrymorse yes, that solves the issue, btw is there any way for doing that with stencil not css?

Comment: I don't know stenciljs, sorry. But it seems strange that a disabled button would receive any click events. Did you view the button's html in the browser source window, just to be sure the disabled attribute is there?

Comment: @terrymorse so techincally a new component will be created around button, the problem is click on the real button and outer component are not tied together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's some confusion about how the `on...` attributes work with custom elements. On a Stencil component, if an attribute starts with `on`, then it becomes a handler for the event with the same name as the rest of the attribute (case is converted automatically). E. g. if your component emits an event called `myEvent` (using Stencil's `@Event` decorator and `EventEmitter` type), then you can add a listener for that event to your component using an `onMyEvent` attribute. This is explained with an example in the docs [here](https://stenciljs.com/docs/events#using-events-in-jsx).

In your case, you're adding an `onClick` attribute to your component, which handles the `click` event for that element, which is a native DOM event that doesn't need to be set up, i. e. any HTML or custom element triggers a `click` event when it is clicked (not just buttons).

So even if your component was just like

```
@Component({ tag: "idv-button" })
export class IdvButton {
    render() {
        return <p>Hello, World!</p>;
    }
}
```

and you used it like

```html
<idv-button onClick={console.log} />
```

you'd still receive the `click` event every time you click the text.

---

What I think you're trying to achieve is to pass the `onClick` handler through to the underlying button. The easiest way to do so is to pass the handler function as a prop.

```
import { Component, h, Host, Prop } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({ tag: "idv-button", shadow: true })
export class IdvButton {
    @Prop() disabled?: boolean;
    @Prop() clickHandler: (e: MouseEvent) => void;

    render() {
        return (
            <button disabled={this.disabled} onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}>
                <slot />
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<idv-button clickHandler={console.log}>
    My Button
</idv-button>
```

Not sure you actually need to bind `this`, and also changed it to pass the content as a slot but feel free to discard that suggestion.

BTW it's quite tempting to call the prop `onClick` but that would clash with the `on...` event handling for the native `click` event, so Stencil would warn you about that at compile-time.

---

Another solution is to add `pointer-events: none` to the host when the `disabled` prop is set. This is what Ionic's `ion-button` does (see [button.tsx#L220](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/67b0853b28f117f35f558993be87186ca548130b/core/src/components/button/button.tsx#L220) and [button.scss#L70-L74](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/67b0853b28f117f35f558993be87186ca548130b/core/src/components/button/button.scss#L70-L74)).

In your case it would be something like

```
import { Component, Host, h, Prop } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({ tag: "idv-button", shadow: true })
export class IdvButton {
    @Prop() disabled?: boolean;

    render() {
        return (
            <Host style={{ pointerEvents: this.disabled ? 'none' : undefined }}>
                <button disabled={this.disabled}>
                    <span class="btn-text">
                        <slot />
                    </span>
                </button>
            </Host>
        );
    }
}
```

(the `onClick` attribute would work automatically on your component because it's a default event)

Answer (score 2):

## Problem Analysis

### Disabled is not Disabled

One problem is, that `<idv-button disabled>` evaluates to `this.disabled===""` (empty string), which is interpreted as `false` instead of `true`.

### Chrome Captures onClick

Another problem, with the above fixed, it then does work in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Chrome does not give you a chance to handle `onClick`on your own, Chrome handles it.

### Reserved onClick

The reserved `onClick` is handled completely differently. All `on…`-properties can take functions in a string in a HTML-environment. But if you define your own function, not named with `on…`-prefix, you cannot add the function directyly in HTML. So, you must define your own function with a different name, because of the special behaviour of `onClick`, so you need to handle it specially in plain HTML. In JSX all is as expected.

Hint: The name `onClick` is reserved, so it is implicit and does not need to be added as `@Prop`.

### Function Properties in Plain HTML

If you need t add a function in an plain HTML environment (not JSX), you need to add the function separately. See also: [Pass functions to stencil component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387964/pass-functions-to-stencil-component).

```
<idv-button>...</idv-button>
<script>
  document.currentScript.previousElementSibling.clickHandler =
      function() { ... }
</script>
```

(add function `clickHandler` to the element above the script)

## Simple Solution

BTW: I prefer to have the text inside the tag, so I use `<slot/>`

### Component Definition

The following solves all these problems and works perfectly:

```
Component({tag: 'idv-button'})

export class IdvButton {

  @Prop() disabled?: any
  @Prop() clickHandler: (e: MouseEvent) => void;

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        disabled={this.disabled || this.disabled === ""}
        onClick={this.clickHandler}
      >
        <slot />
      </button>

    )
  }

}
```

### Use in Non-JSX Plain-HTML

To use that in plain HTML, you need to add the function in separate JavaScript (here I add the same function to all `idv-button`-elements):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="module" src="/build/my-webcomponents.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="/build/my-webcomponents.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <idv-button>Enabled</idv-button>
    <idv-button disabled>Disabled</idv-button>
    <script>
      var allButtonInstances = document.querySelectorAll('idv-button')
      allButtonInstances.forEach(e => e.clickHandler = function() {
        alert('here');
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but, what about using `{...(this.disabled || null)}` instead of `disabled={this.disabled}`?